# Bootstrap Layout Issue - multiple columns tiled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hi I hope someone can help me. I am relatively new to Bootstrap and I can get my head around the column layouts and how they work. However I've come to a problem when I want to create different columns at different heights.

I am trying to achieve the following layout:

[image: Layout]

The issue I have is trying to get **tab3** in that position, I need it stacked **below tab2**. I managed to sort out **tab5** and **6** by adding in a margin as labelled but thought this would be too messy for **tab3**.

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/118335) (thanks @Gorostas)

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/118335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to the grid system of bootstrap you can always make columns inside other columns.
Ill just show the top half since you have done the bottom half.

```
<div class ="container">

    <div class ="row"> <!--Use a Row to keeps columns on the same line for the top half-->

      <div class="col-md-8"> <!--Tab 1-->

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2"> <!--Space for Tab 2 and 3-->

         <div class="row"> <!--Row is not necassery when using 12 but I use them for smaller columns viewed on a smaller viewport-->

            <!-- "col-md12" make use of all spacing of the grid that is available within the parent-->
            <div class="col-md-12"> <!--Uses up full portion of the col-md-2 spacing-->


            </div> <!--Tab 2-->

            <div class="col-md-12"> <!--Uses up full portion of the col-md-2 spacing-->


            </div> <!--Tab 3-->

          </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">


      </div> <!--Tab 4-->

    </div>

    <div class="row">

          <!-- Bottom half of tabs-->

    </div>

</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/wG58MwAews

If you are using the default Bootstrap 3 your grid will be 12 blocks horizontal. If you make a new col in a col it will break that column into 12 and position it relative to the grid system, http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/, you can break it down into another 12 blocks like in my example.Comment if you want a more detailed explanation, but this should do the job.